# How can I use RadioListTile as an item for DropDownMenuItem in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout

What I was trying to achieve was to have a `DropDownMenuItem` displaying as `RadioListTile` so that I'd be able to have a `Radio` and a `Text`. I previously tried using `Row` widget with `Radio` and `Text` as *children* which works but when I click on the Text, it does not effect the **onChanged** property of the `Radio`.

This led me to :

```
 bottomSheet: DropdownButton(
          onChanged: (val) {},
          items: kCategoryList.entries
              .map(
                (e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: catValue,
                  child: RadioListTile(
                    activeColor: kCategoryList[catValue],
                    groupValue: catValue,
                    value: e.key,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {
                        catValue = val;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
      ),
```

and I got the error message:

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderListTile#0cd79 relayoutBoundary=up20 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1694 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
    RadioListTile<String>
```

Here is a picture of what I want to achieve:

[image: What I was trying to achieve]

Comment: Could you maybe share a screenshot of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Done. Just added an image of what I was trying to achieve.